# plugins notation for sub projects

Tags: gradle, bintray

[gradle-bintray-plugin documentation](https://github.com/bintray/gradle-bintray-plugin) says that:

`Currently the "plugins" notation cannot be used for applying the plugin for sub projects, when used from the root build script.`

What does it mean? Should I add plugins notation in every module or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's entirely true. It's possible to use the `plugins` block for multi-module projects.

Give the following a try (untested):

```
plugins {
    id("com.jfrog.bintray") version "1.8.4" apply false
}

subprojects {
    apply {
        plugin("com.jfrog.bintray")
    }
}
```

That should apply it to all subprojects as if you did `plugins {}` in each project.